# Understanding deadline

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

English is my second language and i can get a little confused with time and dates. My Uni has sent me a email with a given deadline and i want to make sure that i understand it. The email stated the following *"you have 14 days from today 5 March to submit your project. Deadline: 20 March 2020."*

So i assume that the deadline is at midnight the 19th March. Because its 14 days from the 5th. But the write that the deadline is the 20th? How can that be when they wrote "14 days from today" which would be the 19th. Do they just mean that i should hand it in before midnight? or do i have to midnight the 20th of march?

Comment: It could just be an error in one direction or the other. Either it's supposed to be the 19th, or it's supposed to be 15 days. They could have miscalculated.

Comment: You make a valid point. I think that they meant 14 days from today excluding the 5th.

Comment: This isn't a question we can answer, partially due to the issue that @MattSamuel identified, and even without that, there's no precise conventional meaning for "Deadline: 20 March." It could mean before 00:01, 20 March; it could mean no later than 23:59, 20 March; it could mean at 09:00, 20 March, when class begins.  The point is, you should get clarification from the person who assigned the deadline.

Comment: It's also very likely that the deadline for *submission* of this assignment is 11:59 PM on March 19th. It's due *by the end of* March 19th, and the first second of March 20th is the earliest it is too late to submit. The English case may be unclear, but the practical case is not: having your assignment submitted before the end of March 19th is the best plan based on the information currently available.

Comment: Thanks Juhasz. I live in Denmark and all schools are closed so i dont have alot of contact with my teacters. But i will ask my teacher about the deadline.

Comment: Generally speaking (in the US), a "deadline on Thursday" would mean that the "cut-off point" is at close-of-business (whatever that means for the facility being discussed) on Thursday.